# find the time period of ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got an ode from a physics problem whose solution should have a period. The ode looks like
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(s-b \arcsin s) + \omega^2 s=0,$$ where $b=\cos\frac{a}{2}$, and $a$ is a constant, $a\in(0,\pi)$. The initial condition is $s(0)=\sin\frac{a}{2}$, $s'(0)=0$. Is it possible to find the period or even sovling the equation?

The problem arose from finding the period of a point oscillating on following curve with y axis downward under gravity:
$$\begin{array}\\ 
x=u+\sin u-4\cos\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{u}{2},\\
y=3+\cos u-4\cos\frac{a}{2}\cos\frac{u}{2},\quad u\in [-a,a].
\end{array}
$$
The curve is an involute of a cycloid, which becomes a cycloid itself when $a=\pi$. I have defined $s=\sin\frac{u}{2}$.

[image]

Comment: This looks rather unusual for an ODE associated with physics. Could you in a short way describe the situation it arose from? // Have you tried setting $y=s-b\arcsin s$ so you get a more standard second order equation?

Comment: Thanks. The physics backgroud is added. //I have tried but still have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: carrying out the differentiations on the LHS produces

$$
s''-b\left(\frac{ss'^2-(s^2-1)s''}{(1-s^2)^{3/2}}\right)+\omega^2s=0
$$

This is an autonomous ODE; *i.e.* there are no explicit appearances of $t$. Substituting

$$
s'(t)=u(s)\qquad
s''(t)=u'(s)u(s)
$$

thereby results in

$$
u'\underbrace{\left(1+b\,\frac{(s^2-1)}{(1-s^2)^{3/2}}\right)}_{A(s)}
=u\underbrace{\left(\frac{bs}{(1-s^2)^{3/2}}\right)}_{\frac12B(s)}
+u^{-1}\underbrace{\left(\omega^2s\right)}_{\frac12C(s)}
$$

which is a Bernoulli equation. Further substituting

$$
\xi(s)=u(s)^2
$$

results in

$$
\xi'=\left(\frac{B(s)}{A(s)}\right)\xi+\frac{C(s)}{A(s)}
$$

This is a first-order linear ODE with the solution

$$
\xi(s)
=\frac{c_1}{I(s)}+\frac{1}{I(s)}\int^sds'\frac{C(s')}{A(s')}\,I(s')
$$

where $I(s)$ is the integrating factor

$$
I(s)
=\exp\left[-\int^sds'\frac{B(s')}{A(s')}\right]
$$